# Guava / testing an iterator implementation

Tags: java, guava

Is it possible to use the Guava testing for iterators? I've tried to extend `IteratorTester`, but `com.google.common.collect.testing.AbstractIteratorTester` isn't public such that it isn't possible to add a constructor. Maybe I have to use another class or it's just not made for the public? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[This example](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/collect/testing/testers/CollectionIteratorTester.java#98) from `CollectionIteratorTester` provides an example of how to build an `IteratorTester`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but my problem is that the KnownOrder enum is defined in AbstractIteratorTest and it's package private if I didn't miss something fundamentally.

Comment: Okay.  Looking at the code, it looks like you can get away with passing `null` instead of `KnownOrder.KNOWN_ORDER`, but I'll see what I can do about fixing that for release 14.0.

Comment: Thanks, then I'm passing null until 14.0.1 is going to be released. BTW: Is it a "Christmas release" or going to be released next year? :-)

Comment: It's kind of horrible, but you can get at KnownOrder by writing "IteratorTester.KnownOrder.KNOWN_ORDER."

(We do intend to get 14.0 out in 2012.)